# Seria possivel converter um formulario para pdf?

Tags: java

Seria possível eu converter um formulário para pdf ou imprimi-lo ? feito em java, e estão em um banco de dados também.

Comment: Voce poderia ser mais especifico? @Prostetnic Vogon Jeltz

Comment: Tenho um formulario de cadastro em um jFrame, que é cadastrado em um bd, gostaria de transformalo em pdf e imprimi-lo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tenta o codigo abaixo se precisar de mais referencias ou exemplos tenta o link abaixo:

Aqui:
https://community.oracle.com/thread/1164777?start=0&tstart=0

E aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17014974/how-do-i-make-a-pdf-of-the-jframe-including-the-jscrollpane-parts-not-shown

```
public void PrintFrameToPDF(File file) {
        try {
            Document d = new Document();
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(d, new FileOutputStream(file));
            d.open();

            PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
            PdfTemplate template = cb.createTemplate(PageSize.A4.getWidth(),PageSize.A4.getHeight());
            cb.addTemplate(template, 0, 0);

            Graphics2D g2d = template.createGraphics(PageSize.A4.getWidth(),PageSize.A4.getHeight());
            g2d.scale(0.4, 0.4);

            for(int i=0; i< this.getContentPane().getComponents().length; i++){
                Component c = this.getContentPane().getComponent(i);
                if(c instanceof JLabel || c instanceof JScrollPane){
                    g2d.translate(c.getBounds().x,c.getBounds().y);
                    if(c instanceof JScrollPane){c.setBounds(0,0,(int)PageSize.A4.getWidth()*2,(int)PageSize.A4.getHeight()*2);}
                    c.paintAll(g2d);
                    c.addNotify();
                }
            }


            g2d.dispose();

            d.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: " + e.toString());
        }
    }
```